# On Click function only working on second click

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Have the following code on a `Wordpress/Woocommerce` build. The issue is the button only works on the second click. Need this to work on the first click, what's wrong with my code?

```
// Add button to hide Personalisation

add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_text', 29);

function custom_text() {
    print '<button class="personlisation-button" onclick="myFunction()">Add Personalisation</button>';  
}
```

```html
// Script to toggle visibility

<script type="text/javascript">
  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("wcj_product_addons");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      x.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Hello,

You should comment the myFunction code and set only alert("Hello"); if on click alert called on the single click it means your function is calling perfectly and the issue will in document.getElementById("wcj_product_addons"); You might be pass wrong id. Please check it let me know if it works, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be good to add a check for `null`. You might have no such element on a page.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("demo");
  if (x != null && x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<button
  onclick="myFunction()"
>
  Toggle</button
>

<div id="demo">Hello world</div>
```